# How to get URL parameters from custom input with JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, view

I have a view that I want to store some URL parameters and have tried everything. Here is my current code.

Sample URL: https://www.facebook.com?username=""&password=""(I'm trying to collect the parameter values)

HTML:

```
<input id="urlInput" type="text" placeholder="Enter URL" class="form-control" />
```

Javascript:

```
var url = $("#urlInput").val();//This pulls the value of the input/URL with parameters
var getURLUser = url.substring(url.indexOf("?"));
$("#urluser").html(getURLUser);
```

What is wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Check this link http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/06/get-url-parameters-using-jquery.html

Comment: Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21903119/10170918) might be help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, you're getting a String from the beginning of `?` to the end of the String.

You could split the string by `&password=`, and get the right side of it:

```
var url = "https://www.facebook.com?username=123&password=(I'm trying to collect the parameter values)";
var getURLUser = url.split("&password=")[1];
// results in "(I'm trying to collect the parameter values)"
console.log(getURLUser);
```

or

```
var url = "https://www.facebook.com?username=123&password=(I'm trying to collect the parameter values)";
var getURLUser = url.split("&password=");
console.log(getURLUser[0]);
// results in "https://www.facebook.com?username=123"
console.log(getURLUser[1]);
// results in "(I'm trying to collect the parameter values)"
```

Comment: I've tried adjusting the numbers, but to no avail. How would you get just the username in the middle? Right now, I have                                                  "var geturlUser = url.split("?username=")[1] && url.split("&password=")[0];"//After the username and before the password?? Same Example applies.

Comment: @MathewDodson `url.split('?username=')[1].split('&password')[0];`

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you.